# PHP get text from tag with regex

Tags: php, regex

i want to get all `text` from thiw blow tag and put thats into array with regex

```
<div class="titr2"><a href="Name.asp?nid=2923">TEXT </a></div>
```

`TEXT` is utf-8 and i can not get that with using regex

```
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$handle='http://www.namefa.ir/Names.asp?pn=3&sx=F&fc=%D8%A8';
$handle = file_get_contents($handle);
preg_match_all('<div class="titr2" href=".*">(.*)<a href=".*"></a></div>)siU', $string, $matching_data);
print_r($matching_data);
?>
```

Comment: Apart from your regular expression being syntactically wrong, you are looking for a `href` attribute on the `div` that’s not there …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this regexp:

```
preg_match_all('/<div[^>]+class="titr2"[^>]*>\s*<a[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>\s*<\/div>/si', $handle, $matching_data);
```

Comment: Do you try to use this pattern? I already tested them myself and it work :)

Comment: yes. this is result:`Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) `

Comment: result of `var_dump($matching_data);` is:`array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } } ` and `var_dump($string)` is `NULL`

Comment: you have empty string.. so result is empty. assign your html code to $string variable

Comment: @TuxWorld Maybe you mean `$handle` instead of `$string` in `preg_match_all` function, check the update, please?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

You should **really** use an HTML parser instead.

If this really is a one-time thing, limited to this case only, in a small HTML file that never changes, your regex is wrong:

```
<div class="titr2"><a href=".+?">(.+?)</a></div>
```

would be closer and you should checkout Victor's solution.

Comment: It's need to escape `/` char like `\/`

Comment: @TuxWorld try to use regex in my answer

Comment: @Victor. can you paste full regex pattern?

Comment: @robin.`preg_match_all('<div class="titr2"><a href=".+">(.+?)</a></div>', $string, $matching_data);`

Comment: @TuxWorld I put full regex in my answer

Comment: Not necessarily, `/` isn't a regex reserved character. It depends on the pattern delimiter you're using, and here in the question there's just a typo `)` as a delimiter. @TuxWorld, you could probably use `'/<div class="titr2"><a href=".+?">(.+?)<\/a><\/div>/'` indeed. But really, the parser thing.

Comment: @Robin.that return null array.

Comment: Victor's regex is more efficient, you should try it if you must. But one last time, regex is very probably not the tool you want.